# Triggering animation of easypiechart.js with waypoints

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts

I'm trying to bind animated charts build with [easypiechart.js](http://rendro.github.io/easy-pie-chart/) to [waypoints](http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/), so that animation will trigger only when user scrolls down to charts. Script that creates charts looks like that:

```
$(function(){
$('.chart').easyPieChart({
        easing: 'easeOutBounce',
        barColor:'#545ec4',
        trackColor:'#ccc',
        scaleColor:false,
        lineWidth:2,
        size:191,
        lineCap:'circle',
        onStep: function(from, to, percent) {
            $(this.el).find('.percent').text(Math.round(percent));
        }
    });
});
```

However, when I'm trying to wrap this function into waypoints function, it doesn't work at all, even charts dissapear.

I do it like this:

```
$('.chart').waypoint(function(event, direction) {
    $('.chart').easyPieChart({
        easing: 'easeOutBounce',
        barColor:'#545ec4',
        trackColor:'#ccc',
        scaleColor:false,
        lineWidth:2,
        size:191,
        lineCap:'circle',
        onStep: function(from, to, percent) {
            $(this.el).find('.percent').text(Math.round(percent));
        }
    });
},{
  triggerOnce: true,
  offset: 'bottom-in-view'
});
```

Any explanation or correction will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Hi i am using this script and it works fine for me

```
$('.chart').waypoint(function() {
                      $(this).easyPieChart({
                        animate: 2000,
                        scaleColor: false,
                        trackColor: '#e5e5e5',
                        barColor: '#f36640',
                        lineWidth: 14,
                        size: 175,
                      });
                    }, {
                      triggerOnce: true,
                      offset: 'bottom-in-view'
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try wrapping the easy pie chart function in another function and calling that from the waypoint function? Not sure if that would even matter...